# Javascript doesn't return an html element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Been trying to do some project for myself to practice react because I'm new and i've got into trouble that no matter what, it doesn't return the html from the javascript after using map inside map

```
import './App.css';
import data from './data.json';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  const keys = Object.keys(data)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
         {keys.map(key => {
           if (key !== "events"){
               return (<h1 className="data">{key} : {data[key]}</h1>);
           }else{
             data["events"].map(event => {
               return (<h1 className="event_data"> {event["name"]} value was changed to {event["state"]} in {event["date"]} </h1>);
             })
           }
         })
        }
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is there there any kind of reason why it doesn't work? and how do I fix it?

Comment: Typo: You ignored the return value of the map: `data["events"].map(event => {` so if it hits the else branch it returns undefined.

Answer (score 1):

this branch:

```
           }else{
             data["events"].map(event => {
               return (<h1 className="event_data"> {event["name"]} value was changed to {event["state"]} in {event["date"]} </h1>);
             })
           }
```

doesn't return the elements. You need `return data['events'].map...`

Answer (score 0):

You need first to declare a class for your app. Then define a render function inside to print the html to the DOM.

Try this:

```
import './App.css';
import data from './data.json';

import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  
  render() {

    const keys = Object.keys(data)
    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
           {keys.map(key => {
             if (key !== "events"){
                 return (<h1 className="data">{key} : {data[key]}</h1>);
             }else{
               data["events"].map(event => {
                 return (<h1 className="event_data"> {event["name"]} value was changed to {event["state"]} in {event["date"]} </h1>);
               })
             }
           })
          }
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```